# Getting NaN from url parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I am fairly new to Angular 4. So I don't know how to resolve this.

Here is the code in the Component.

```
  public ngOnInit() {
   this._loginResSub = this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this._loginService.getResources(+params['tId']))
    .subscribe((_res) => {
    console.log(_res);
  });
}
```

Here is the service method.

```
public getResources(tId: any): Observable<ILoginRes>{
    console.log(tId);
        return this.http
        .get(CONFIG.urls.loginresources + '?tId=' + tId)
        .map((response) => {
            let logRes: any = response.json();
            return (logRes as ILoginRes); 
        })
        .share()
        .catch(this.exceptionService.catchBadResponse)
        .finally(() => console.log('getResources() ended'));
}
```

As you can see I am logging in the console 'tId'. But I am getting NaN in the console. I have configured routing module.

```
  const loginRoutes: Routes = [
  {
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/login/default/:tId',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'default/:tId',
      component: LoginFormComponent
    },
    ]
  }
];
```

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I tried removing the plus before params. Now I am getting undefined.

Comment: what is `this.route`??

Comment: @RameshRajendran ActivatedRoute I guess.

Comment: `path: '', redirectTo: '/login/default/:tId'` here you redirect to something unknown, to a url with string `:tId` at the end. Try to redirect it to `/login/default/1` for example - so that you can cast it to number.

Comment: Still same. Getting NaN.